# concatenate names across rows on Groupby with nan filled out

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have this data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['US123','Brown, Alan'],['CA456', 'Powell, Jared'], ['US123', np.nan],['US123','Rebecca, Julia'], ['CA456', 'Mike, Joe']], columns=['ID', 'Name'])
df
```

[image]

I want the result like below:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Try `df.groupby('ID')['Name'].agg(': '.join)` Well.. because fo the NaN try `df.groupby('ID')['Name'].agg(lambda x: '; '.join(x.dropna()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)[['Name']].agg(lambda x: '; '.join(x.dropna()))
```

Output:

```
      ID                         Name
0  CA456     Powell, Jared; Mike, Joe
1  US123  Brown, Alan; Rebecca, Julia
```

Comment: maybe dropping the nulls before joining will be faster? just a thought

Comment: That works well! Thank you very much! I was actually doing some crazy stuff - define a function and then apply it to Groupby object. But this is much easier!

Answer (score 0):

another method would be to set the ID as the index and use `stack` this will remove any NA rows by default.

```
df.set_index('ID').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(names=';'.join).reset_index()

      ID                       names
0  CA456     Powell, Jared;Mike, Joe
1  US123  Brown, Alan;Rebecca, Julia
```